# .htaccess redirect only working for part of the URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a bunch of URLs from an old site to the shiny relaunched site. My .htaccess is working with the first level of directories (i.e. example.com/directory is redirecting to example.com/newdirectory), but I'm having issues redirecting beneath that. Here's an example of one that's not working:

```
Redirect 301 /Expertise/QuantitativeResearch/ /services/quantitative-research/
```

This goes to example.com/services/QuantitativeResearch - so the Expertise directory is being redirected, but the QuantitativeResearch part of the URL isn't.

I've tried changing it to RedirectMatch301, but it doesn't help. I'm wondering if I need to strip out /Expertise/ and use some Regex instead? The /Expertise/ part is already being redirected to /services/ by another line:

```
Redirect 301 /Expertise/ /services/
```

Could this be causing conflict? I know I'm probably missing something really basic here! Just to clarify, my redirects are all coming after  and before RewriteEngine On.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to use regex based matching here. Try `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Expertise/QuantitativeResearch/?$ /services/quantitative-research/

RedirectMatch 301 ^/Expertise/(.*)$ /services/$1
```

Comment: Shouldn't your second redirect be in first position ? Otherwise current first one is matching everything under `/Expertise/`

Comment: Thanks both! This is working, though I've now got another issue - when you search for this Company, there's a link in the search results that's www.example.com/Expertise/ProductTesting. Clicking on it strips the www (which it's supposed to), but then still goes to example.com/services/ProductTesting. When you just type the URL in (i.e. example.com/Expertise/ProductTesting) it does redirect, so I don't understand why it's not doing that via the Google result.

Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: @fincherley: It is better to keep one post for one problem since other problem may be different in nature and would require different rule. If current question has been answered then mark this answer as accepted and post a new question so that you can better answers. Comments section is not the place to ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava - have done so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665943/link-in-google-search-results-is-not-redirected-to-expected-page-as-per-htacces)

Comment: You're welcome, I will take a look at your new question if it is not answered already.