# Link in Google search results is not redirected to expected page as per .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I originally asked a .htaccess question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646268/htaccess-redirect-only-working-for-part-of-the-url/25646424#25646424) and got some awesome help, which worked a treat. Basically, I'm trying to redirect pages from an old site to a new site, and have managed to make most things work. However, there's a couple of links in Google's search results that aren't redirecting properly, and I believe this is because they're all www and the new site redirects to non-www. For example, a link like this in the search engine results:

www.example.com/Expertise/ProductTesting

Should go to:

example.com/services/product-testing

But instead goes to:

example.com/services/ProductTesting

So for some reason the last part of the URL isn't changing. Here's how that line looks in my .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Expertise/ProductTesting/?$ /services/product-testing/
```

If I type the address in manually and drop the www, it redirects as it should.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your previous question into consideration, you must put your new rule **before** the one that is matching everything: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/Expertise/(.*)$ /services/$1`.

Also, you'll maybe have to clear your browser's cache before trying again (or try it with another browser).

Your rules should look like this

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Expertise/QuantitativeResearch/?$ /services/quantitative-research/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Expertise/ProductTesting/?$ /services/product-testing/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Expertise/(.*)$ /services/$1
```

Comment: Thanks @Justin - that's done the job! I think the main issue may have been the cache in this case, but either way, it's working brilliantly now.